# In Scala: How to recursively pass a function as an argument to a function call in its own body

Tags: scala

I'm trying to refactor some code and use higher-order functions. but for some reason when I pass the function as an argument to a function in its own body. I get the error Cannot resolve reference 'weight' with such signature.

here's my code:

```
abstract class CodeTree
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree  

def walk[T](t: CodeTree, op: CodeTree => T, cmb: (T,T) => T) = t match {
  case Fork(l,r,_,_) => cmb(op(l), op(r))
  case Leaf(_,x)     => x
}

def weight(tree: CodeTree): Int = walk[Int](tree, weight, _ ++ _)

def chars(tree: CodeTree): List[Char] = tree match {
  case Fork(l,r,x,_) => chars(l) ++ chars(r)
  case Leaf(x,_)     => List(x)
}
```

Comment: Those parentheses after `weight` look wrong (especially with the comma right after the opening parenthesis). Did you maybe mean `walk(tree, weight, _ ++ _)`?

Comment: was also just looking into it: I see you edited the code, it didn't fix the issue?

Comment: `weight` returns an `Int` but you say `_ ++ _`. There's no operation `++` on `Int`s. Am I right?

Comment: Also, `walk` doesn't return a `T`! Put a return type `: T` and see the error.

Comment: The [`matryoshka`](https://github.com/slamdata/matryoshka) library provides general recursion schemes if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess walk method should return `T` and `++` should be `+`, is this what you were trying to do?

```
abstract class CodeTree
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree  

def walk[T](t: CodeTree, op: CodeTree => T, cmb: (T,T) => T): T = t match {
  case Fork(l,r,_,_) => cmb(op(l), op(r))
  case t: Leaf     => op(t)
}

def weight(tree: CodeTree): Int = walk[Int](tree, weight, _ + _)

def chars(tree: CodeTree): List[Char] = tree match {
  case Fork(l,r,x,_) => chars(l) ++ chars(r)
  case Leaf(x,_)     => List(x)
}
```